# Nested CSS calc not working on IE 11 and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I trying to scale a div height using the following CSS code. everything was working fine on Chrome and FF browser but it's not working on IE11 and IE Edge.

Chrome & FF:

```css
Height:calc((100vh - 100%) + 30px);
```

When I try to put on Edge inspect its converted to:

```css
Height:calc(30px + 100vh + -100%);


.flyout-container {
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px!important;
    bottom: auto;
    right: 0;
    width: 464px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #81d8d0;
    max-height: inherit;
    transition: .4s ease;
    padding: 0 16px 0 2.5vw;
    height: 0;
}


.flyout-container.active {
    padding-top: 2.5vw;
    bottom: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: none;
    height: calc((100vh - 100%) + 30px);
}
```

Is there anything I can do to make IE correctly render calc()?

Comment: My first thought would be, perhaps: `Height:calc( calc(100vh - 100%) + 30px);` but I'm surprised that it might be necessary, and I haven't tried it to check.

Comment: Are those parenthesis really necessary?

Comment: share full code, I suspect it has something to do with percentage value and not the calc()

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have tried to create a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/68sey1mn/) using calc(), it works well in IE 11, so I support perhaps the issue is related to the expression values.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis are not necessary in the provided example.
Additions and subtractions follow the commutative rule denoting there is no point in parenthesizing them.

Your problem might be caused by the percentage values you're using.
Please provide the full code in order to inspect what's preventing the anticipated behaviour.

Though, `calc()` is not fully supported in IE as there are loads of known issues.
Please have a look at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc) to see what's not working as expected.